# can not import correctly package when have the same package-name in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my workspace, there are several directores(projects). All the directories have the same stucture, like :

```
project1:
    docs/
    src/
        __init__.py
        code1.py
    test/
projects2:
    docs/
    src/
         __init__.py
        code2.py
   test/
projects3:
    docs/
    src/
       __init__.py
      code3.py
...

# .env file in workspace
#   PYTHONPATH=project1:project2:project3
When i want import package from code2, it would fail, such as code3.py
# code3.py 
# from src import code2
```

I know in pycharm , it is easy to do with this situation by just marketing the directories as source root directory.

How can i do with it?

VS Code version: Code 1.43.2 (0ba0ca5, 2020-03-24T07:34:57.037Z)
OS version: Darwin x64 18.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by install extensions: Python/Python extension Pack/magic python
Mainly the Python Extension Pack. 
When this extension enabled, others enabled, also, when it is disabled, others disabled also.